# problem with getting unison-gtk2 to run on mac

Tags: synchronization, unison

Probably I'm not doing this right, but I'm trying to get the gui-version of unison to run on my mac (Big Sur 11.4), but when I download binary release (https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/releases) and run `unison-gtk2`, it says `Warning: DISPLAY not set or empty; starting the Text UI` in the output. I also tried to build from source with `make UISTYLE=macnew` but it didn't build the gui app. The releases I found where all for Catalina, which could be the issue. Which version should I try to install, and how, if I want the GUI version? (I was able to update the text-version of unison using homebrew, but I think I can't get the gui with brew, or can I?)

Comment: Hi, I'm not familiar with Mac at all, but the message you are getting suggests that the GUI version did start, but it just couldn't connect to the (graphical) display (a.k.a. X server). I would focus my troubleshooting efforts on that `DISPLAY not set or empty` message. HTH!

Comment: That sounds right, but do I need to specify a display by providing an additional argument? Or is this likely to be a compatibility issue with the operating system?

Comment: Unfortunately I've got no clue how to get this working on Mac (anyone with experience chime in?). On Linux, the `DISPLAY` environment variable would likely be set already, unless you're doing something weird (like running a shell that doesn't run in a graphical window manager). Could you try and run `unison` from within a shell? Possibly printing out the value of that environment variable `DISPLAY` perhaps?

Comment: I think I was doing something weird then, I was just tryting to run it in Terminal, and `echo $DISPLAY` returns no value, so presumably I'd need a different shell that has a graphical window manager. What I would really like to do though is to compile the unison app, which is how I had been running unison before.

Comment: When I download the precompiled app (e.g. at https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/releases/download/v2.51.4/Unison-v2.51.4.ocaml-4.08.1.macos-10.15.app.tar.gz) and run it I get an error though because it says the app is damaged. (again, this may be an OS compatibility issue). So ideally what I'd need is intructions how to build the app in a way that is OS Big Sur compatible. It's very possible though that I'm doing something wrong

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you much, sorry ... Would perhaps development versions of certain libraries you might need be missing? (Does Mac even work that way?)

Answer (score 2):

Replying to @mchlmchl

Fix the "app is damaged" error by putting it in the Applications folder and running the following command:

```
xattr -cr /Applications/Unison.app
```

Source: https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/wiki/CI-Binary-instructions

[Download the precompiled app v2.51.4](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/releases/download/v2.51.4/Unison-v2.51.4.ocaml-4.08.1.macos-10.15.app.tar.gz)

This works on my MacBook Pro 16inch running macOS Big Sur 11.6.